# Acces objects contents while creating

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

I am trying to create a big object containing api path variables. 
I need to be able to make changes to the apis paths often, for migrating the application, so I was hoping to create some base paths in one file, and follow the scheme of my api documentation in postman.
This is the way I was hoping to be able to use:

```
export const BASES = {
  OD: {
    BASE: `${urlbase}/od/`,
    READ: `${BASES.OD.BASE}/read/v1/`,
    WRITE: `${BASES.OD.BASE}/write/v3`,
  },
  WH: {
    BASE: `${urlbasenew}/wh/`,
    EX: `${BASES.WH.BASE}/ex`,
  },
};
```

And then access the path via BASES.OD.READ and so on...

Now I get the error

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'BASES' before initialization
```

Which seems logical to me. Is there an elegant way of handling this? (Or maybe I am just blind)
Googling the error does not help, no one tried this seemingly.

Comment: please post your code of initialise place or error shown page

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is to extract the BASE urls so you can use them in many parts of your object:

```
const odBase = `${urlbase}/od/`
const whBase = `${urlbasenew}/wh/`;

export const BASES = {
  OD: {
    BASE: odBase,
    READ: `${odBase}/read/v1/`,
    WRITE: `${odBase}/write/v3`,
  },
  WH: {
    BASE: whBase,
    EX: `${whBase}/ex`,
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was also thinking about this, but then I cannot nest the object deeper. if i wanted to create a new "level" , i would have to create a new const and loose the nice object structure